# How to roll back a google app engine transaction via web interface?

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried to update my app on google appengine by my wireless dropped during the process. When i tried again i got an error "Another transaction by user ajakimov is already in progress for this app and major version." I know i can rollback the update using "appcfg.sh -e [mygmail] rollback [war path]" but i was wondering if it's possible to do this via some sort of a web interfiace (i tried the dashboard i couldn't find anything) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to use the command line tools.